# Can promises be used to ensure data from AJAX request is not used before the request completes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am writing an app in AngularJs, and I am having some conceptual difficulties regarding promises.  More specifically, the role of promises in asynchronously pulling data from an api.

When a user loads the app, the following should happen:

1. Send AJAX request to api.
2. Render View.
3. Receive response from api.
4. Do stuff with data.

However since the AJAX request (by definition) is asynchronous, the app tries to do stuff with the data before it is returned by the server, which causes object is undefined errors and the like.

At the I have a service something like this

```
app.service('bookService', ['$http', function($http){
    var someData;
    $http.get('Some URL').success(function (data){
        someData = data.someData;
    });

    var bookService = {};

    bookService.getSomeData = function (){
        return someData;
    };

    return bookService;
}]);
```

And a controller like this

```
app.controller('BookController', ['bookService', function(bookService){

    console.log(bookService.getSomeData().property);
}]);
```

The controller loads as soon as the attached view is displayed, and attempts to do something with the `someData` object.  At that point it is still undefined (the http request has not yet returned) an errors occur.

Instead I though something like this might work :

```
app.service('bookService', ['$http', function($http){
    var someDataPromise = $http.get('Some URL');

    var bookService = {};

    bookService.getSomeData = function (){
        someDataPromise.success(function (data){
            // This should return the data contained by the promise to the caller
            // of the bookService.getSomeData function.
        });
    };

    return bookService;
}]);
```

The controller would be as before.

My experience with promises, and JavaScript as whole (especially concepts like callbacks and anonymous functions) are quite weak.  My suspicion is that, as concept, this probably works, although probably not in the way I have showed here.

Can promises be used in the way that I have shown here, or am I lacking in understanding as to what is going on here?

Comment: When you fetch data using an asynchronous operation as in your `$http.get()`, that data arrives back sometime later.  Meanwhile, the rest of your function continues to run and actually finishes.  So, you cannot return data such as your `someData` or use it in another method the way you are trying to do.  Instead, the ONLY thing you can do with the data is consume it in the callback where it's first present or call some other function and pass that data to that function.  You can also stuff it into a variable of higher scope - though that is rarely useful because nothing else knows the timing.

Comment: An important thing here for you to understand is that `getSomeData()` cannot return the data that it retrieves.  It will finish executing long before the data is available.  You will either need to return a promise from `getSomeData()` and the caller can use a `.then()` handler on that promise to get access to the data (that's really just a glorified callback with some other nifty features) or you can pass in a callback to `getSomeData()` and you call that callback and pass it the data when it's available.  My recommendation would be to go the promise route.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the elaboration.  I wanted to keep code that pull data from the api, and code that uses said data segregated, as the api is liable to change in the future. That might not be as easily possible as I hoped.  Can change your comments to an answer?  They explained the concept very well and deserve an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider changing your service to return a promise as well:

```
app.service('bookService', ['$http', function($http){
    var bookService = {};

    bookService.getSomeData = function (){
        return $http.get('Some URL');
    });

    return bookService;
}]);
```

then your controller can use promises too:

```
app.controller('BookController', ['bookService', '$scope', function(bookService, $scope){
    bookService.getSomeData().success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

Your service would usually do a bit more than just retrieve the data but hopefully this demonstrates the concept.

It's worth noting that Angular's data binding will pick up the data as soon as you set it on the scope.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I thought that promises created by the $http service somehow required the $http service in order to be used.  ie. it would be necessary to inject the $http service into the controller as well.  I take it that is not the case?

Comment: No, the promise is agnostic of the `$http`; it's actually produced by the [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service. You don't need a reference to either in the consumer in order to handle success/failure.